# Firefox addon: submit link to multiple social services/sites?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, social-networking

Is there any tool or Mozilla Firefox addon to submit links to social networking sites/services (such as Twitter, Facebook, Digg, Delicious, etc) with *one click*?

**Edit:**  The first time it is used, there should be option to add my login info on the different social networking sites/services.  Next, if I submit link, then it should publish on all selected services.

I **don't want to click on individual service button** (like Google toolbar share button) to submit. Rather, I want to click on *one button* to submit link on all services having login info.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently this extension does what you ask : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1833.

I did not tried it.

Answer (score -1):

I use [ShareThis](http://sharethis.com/) which has a [FF extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5000)